# Push Rails app with gem 'eventmachine' on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, eventmachine

Heroku is trying to install the `gem 'eventmachine'`, even if it is in `:development` group. How to fix that?

```
# Gemfile
gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

...

group :development do
    gem 'eventmachine', '1.0.0.beta.4.1'
    gem 'guard-livereload'
end
```

Error message

```
Could not find gem 'eventmachine (= 1.0.0.beta.4.1, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually Heroku should not be trying to install anything from `:development` and `:test` groups. You can however explicitly exclude those groups by setting:

```
heroku config:add BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test"
```

Comment: Well, that's what they are documenting: http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/2/15/using-bundler-groups-on-heroku/

Comment: what's the RACK_ENV configured for your Heroku app?

Comment: You mean? `$ heroku config` -> `RACK_ENV=production`

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same problem. Did you commit your changes to git after running `bundle update`? I forgot to do so, so when I ran `git push heroku master` it was still using my old `Gemfile.lock`. Once I checked in, deployment to heroku ran without issue.

Comment: But, heroku don't use Gemfile.lock (at least for me) `Windows Gemfile.lock detected, ignoring it.`